# How to position text in a DIV without affecting the containing DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm setting up a simple monitoring solution. I've used DevExtreme Scripts to render the gauges. However, they don't provide a native way to display the current value in the middle of the gauge which is what I need. I've managed to create a DIV inside the DIV which contains the gauge. I've set both the container DIV and the DIV which contains the text to position:relative but affects the positioning of the gauge which I don't want.

I've tried using absolute positioning which I can only get to work with one window size. I would like the text position to be the same relative to the gauge whatever size/resolution the window is.

I'm not sure which section of code will be relevant so here is the whole HTML below. However, the CSS relevant to the gauge container is "sensor1" and the text CSS relevant to the value within the gauge DIV is "rpm-value-base"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery341.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>

        <!-- DevExtreme themes -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dx.common.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dx.darkmoon.css">

        <!-- DevExtreme library -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dx.all.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                update();
                setInterval(update, 5000);
            });     
        </script>

        <style>

            *{
                box-sizing: border-box;
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            body {
                margin: 0%;
                background-color: #131820;
            }   

            .wrapper {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
                display: grid;
                grid-gap: 10px;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
                grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 1fr);
            }

            .box {
                background-color: #303c4f;
                border-radius: 5px;
                padding: 5px;
                font-size: 150%;
            }

            .box .box {
                background-color: #303c4f;
            }

            .fan1 {
                grid-column-start: 1;
                grid-column-end: 2;
                grid-row-start: 1;
                grid-row-end: 2;
                display: grid;
                grid-gap: 0px;
                grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
            }
            .fan2 {
                grid-column-start: 2;
                grid-column-end: 3;
                grid-row-start: 1;
                grid-row-end: 2;
                display: grid;
                grid-gap: 0px;
                grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
            }
            .fan3 {
                grid-column-start: 3;
                grid-column-end: 4;
                grid-row-start: 1;
                grid-row-end: 2;
                display: grid;
                grid-gap: 0px;
                grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
            }
            .fan4 {
                grid-column-start: 4;
                grid-column-end: 5;
                grid-row-start: 1;
                grid-row-end: 2;
                display: grid;
                grid-gap: 0px;
                grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
            }
            .fandetails {
                grid-column-start: 5;
                grid-column-end: 6;
                grid-row-start: 1;
                grid-row-end: 2;
                display: grid;
                grid-gap: 10px;
                grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
            }
            .sensor1 {
                position: relative;
                grid-column-start: 1;
                grid-column-end: 2;
                grid-row-start: 2;
                grid-row-end: 3;
            }
            .sensor2 {
                position: relative;
                grid-column-start: 2;
                grid-column-end: 3;
                grid-row-start: 2;
                grid-row-end: 3;
            }
            .sensor3 {
                position: relative;
                grid-column-start: 3;
                grid-column-end: 4;
                grid-row-start: 2;
                grid-row-end: 3;
            }
            .sensor4 {
                position: relative;
                grid-column-start: 4;
                grid-column-end: 5;
                grid-row-start: 2;
                grid-row-end: 3;
            }
            .sensor5 {
                position: relative;
                grid-column-start: 5;
                grid-column-end: 6;
                grid-row-start: 2;
                grid-row-end: 3;
            }

            .rpm-value-base {
                position: relative;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-align: center;
                width: 5%;
                height: 5%;
                left: 45%;
                top: 80%;
            }

        </style>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div class="wrapper"> 
            <div class="box fan1">
                <div id="fan1a" class="box"></div>
                <div id="fan1b" class="box"></div>
            </div>  
            <div class="box fan2">
                <div id="fan2a" class="box"></div>
                <div id="fan2b" class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box fan3">
                <div id="fan3a" class="box"></div>
                <div id="fan3b" class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box fan4">
                <div id="fan4a" class="box"></div>
                <div id="fan4b" class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box fandetails">
                <div id="fandetailsa" class="box"></div>
                <div id="fandetailsb" class="box"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box sensor1" id="sensor1id">
                <div class="rpm-value-base" id="rpm1-value"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="box sensor2" id="sensor2id">

            </div>
            <div class="box sensor3" id="sensor3id">

            </div>
            <div class="box sensor4" id="sensor4id">

            </div>
            <div class="box sensor5" id="sensor5id">

            </div>

        </div>  

        <script>

            $(function() {
                var options_fan_speed = {
                    valueIndicator: {
                        type: 'triangleMarker',
                        color: '#ffffff'
                    },
                    title: {
                        font: {
                            size: 12,
                            weight: 400,
                            color: '#ffffff'
                        }
                    },
                    rangeContainer: {
                        palette: "Pastel",
                        ranges: [
                            { startValue: 0, endValue: 25 },
                            { startValue: 25, endValue: 50 },
                            { startValue: 50, endValue: 75 },
                            { startValue: 75, endValue: 100 }
                        ]
                    }
                };

                var options_fan_rpm = {
                    valueIndicator: {
                        type: 'triangleMarker',
                        color: '#ffffff'
                    },
                    title: {
                        font: {
                            size: 12,
                            weight: 400,
                            color: '#ffffff'
                        }
                    },
                    rangeContainer: {
                        palette: "Pastel",
                        ranges: [
                            { startValue: 0, endValue: 440 },
                            { startValue: 440, endValue: 880 },
                            { startValue: 880, endValue: 1320 },
                            { startValue: 1320, endValue: 1760 },
                            { startValue: 1760, endValue: 2200 }
                        ]
                    }
                };

                $("#fan1a").dxLinearGauge($.extend(true, {}, options_fan_speed, {
                    scale: {
                        startValue: 0, endValue: 100,
                        tickInterval: 25,
                        label: {
                            customizeText: function (arg) {
                                return arg.valueText;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fan 1 Set Speed (%)',
                    }
                }));

                $("#fan1b").dxLinearGauge($.extend(true, {}, options_fan_rpm, {
                    scale: {
                        startValue: 0, endValue: 2200,
                        tickInterval: 440,
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fan 1 RPM',
                    }               
                }));

                $("#fan2a").dxLinearGauge($.extend(true, {}, options_fan_speed, {
                    scale: {
                        startValue: 0, endValue: 100,
                        tickInterval: 25,
                        label: {
                            customizeText: function (arg) {
                                return arg.valueText;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fan 2 Set Speed (%)',
                    }
                }));

                $("#fan2b").dxLinearGauge($.extend(true, {}, options_fan_rpm, {
                    scale: {
                        startValue: 0, endValue: 2200,
                        tickInterval: 440,
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fan 2 RPM',
                    }               
                }));    

                $("#fan3a").dxLinearGauge($.extend(true, {}, options_fan_speed, {
                    scale: {
                        startValue: 0, endValue: 100,
                        tickInterval: 25,
                        label: {
                            customizeText: function (arg) {
                                return arg.valueText;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fan 3 Set Speed (%)',
                    }
                }));

                $("#fan3b").dxLinearGauge($.extend(true, {}, options_fan_rpm, {
                    scale: {
                        startValue: 0, endValue: 2200,
                        tickInterval: 440,
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fan 3 RPM',
                    }               
                }));

                $("#fan4a").dxLinearGauge($.extend(true, {}, options_fan_speed, {
                    scale: {
                        startValue: 0, endValue: 100,
                        tickInterval: 25,
                        label: {
                            customizeText: function (arg) {
                                return arg.valueText;
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fan 4 Set Speed (%)',
                    }
                }));

                $("#fan4b").dxLinearGauge($.extend(true, {}, options_fan_rpm, {
                    scale: {
                        startValue: 0, endValue: 2200,
                        tickInterval: 440,
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: 'Fan 4 RPM',
                    }               
                }));

                var options_sensor = {
                    scale: {
                        startValue: -10,
                        endValue: 40,
                        tickInterval: 5,
                        label: {
                            useRangeColors: true
                        }
                    },
                    rangeContainer: {
                        palette: "Pastel",
                        ranges: [
                            { startValue: -10, endValue: 0, color: '#779ECB' },
                            { startValue: 0, endValue: 10 },
                            { startValue: 10, endValue: 20 },
                            { startValue: 20, endValue: 25 },
                            { startValue: 25, endValue: 40 }
                        ]
                    },
                    valueIndicator: {
                        type: "twoColorNeedle",
                        color: "#779ECB",
                        secondColor: "#dddddd"
                    },
                    title: {
                        font: { size: 12 }
                    }   
                };

                $("#sensor1id").dxCircularGauge($.extend(true, {}, options_sensor, {
                    title: {
                        text: "Cab 1"
                    }       
                }));

                $("#sensor2id").dxCircularGauge($.extend(true, {}, options_sensor, {
                    title: {
                        text: "Cab 2"
                    }       
                }));

                $("#sensor3id").dxCircularGauge($.extend(true, {}, options_sensor, {
                    title: {
                        text: "Loft"
                    }       
                }));

                $("#sensor4id").dxCircularGauge($.extend(true, {}, options_sensor, {
                    title: {
                        text: "Outside"
                    }       
                }));

                $("#sensor5id").dxCircularGauge($.extend(true, {}, options_sensor, {
                    title: {
                        text: "Inside"
                    }       
                }));

            });

        </script>

    </body>

</html>
```

The image shows how I've attempted to overlay the gauge value text on the first sensor "cab1" which works but positions the gauge further down the page. The other gauges show the intended position of the gauges. I've highlighted the gauge value and the "whitespace" created by it.

[Gauges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZQfh.png)

Comment: Hi djmattc.. please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agreed that we need a reproducible example, best as a code snippet, but from what I can see just form your code, I'd try something in this direction:

```css
            .rpm-value-base {
                position: absolute; left: 0; right: 0, bottom: 10%;
                color: #ffffff;
                font-size: 14px;
                text-align: center;
            }
```

e.g. try the absolute positioning from the bottom, not from the top and of course you have to play with the value to see what works.

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou @exside

From your example, I used the following and it works on all gauges.

```
.rpm-value {
    position: absolute; left: 0%; bottom: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    color: #dddddd;
    font-size: calc(7px + 1vw);
    text-align: center;
}
```

[All gauges](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IUhVY.png)